# Does 好 mean "it's better to" or "in order to" in complex sentences? E.g. 今天天气不好，咱们好留在家

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of 好 in the following sentences?

1. 今天天气不好，咱们好留在家
2. 你要支持治病，好早一点恢复健康

Is it "it's better to" or "in order to"?

Comment: 1st sentence is strange, not sure what does it mean, 2nd means "in order to (only good things of course)"

Answer (score 4):

There are some errors about your sentences:

1)今天天气不好，咱们好留在家 could be: 今天天气不好，咱们**最好**留在家.

2)你要支持治病，好早一点恢复健康 could be: 你要**配合治疗**，好早一点恢复健康。 支持治病 sounds odd.

Answer (score 2):

The proper term is "最好" in the first sentence

> 今天天气不好，咱们(**最好**)留在家
>
> Today's weather is bad, we (**better**) stay home

The proper term is "好讓" in the second sentence

> 你要持續治療，(**好讓**)健康早一点恢复
>
> You have to continue the treatment (**in order to let**) your health recover faster

Similar term: 好教 (in order to make)

Example:

"你要努力工作，(**好讓**)父母安心" - "You have to work hard (**in order to let**) your parents have peace of mind."

"你要努力工作，(**好教**)父母安心" - "You have to work hard (**in order to make**) your parents have peace of mind."